# Two identical preprocessor definitions give different results

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Consider the snippet:

```
#define CAT(a, b) a##b

#define M_0 CAT(x, y)
#define M(a) CAT(M_, a)()
M(0);

#define N_0() CAT(x, y)
#define N(a) CAT(N_, a)()
N(0);
```

To me both definitions of `M(a)` and `N(a)` look identical.
However, `cpp` of GCC 4.6.1 expands this to:

```
CAT(x, y)();
xy;
```

Why?

Comment: This old chestnut again. Please don't plagiarize without at least doing the original authors the courtesy of citing the sources. (The answer: One macro takes arguments (zero in number), the other doesn't.)

Comment: @KerrekSB, I didn't notice the difference, honestly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define M_0 CAT(x, y)
#define N_0() CAT(x, y)
```

`M_0` is a simple text replacement. `N_0` is a macro function that, when being evaluated, evaluates any other macro functions as necessary.

Comment: Well, I expected this kind of a solution. Thank you.